# How to find all combinations of integers in a list that have the same sum?

Tags: javascript, c#, php, algorithm, graph

For example I have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and want to find all possible combinations  equal to 100 with operations like (plus, minus, concatenation). Considering + operation one such combination is  [1 + 23 - 4 + 56 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 100].

Comment: Can you use the same number twice ?

Comment: Please choose the language which you are using and please [show your efforts](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: Yes, we can use the same numbers but not the same combinations, sorry Camilo Terevinto but i dont have idea how to make it thats why i dont post any code. The language doesnt matter i need it in php, but i just need the algorithm. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be a fun question to try and solve but I'm sure it will be closed before me or anyone else has time to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's generate *all possible formulas* (you don't have many of them, just `3**9 == 19683`): **C#** code here and below

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Formulas() {
  string[] delimiters = new string[] {
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
  };

  do {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < delimiters.Length; ++i) {
      sb.Append(delimiters[i]);
      sb.Append(i + 1);
    }

    yield return sb.ToString().TrimStart('+');

    for (int i = 0; i < delimiters.Length; ++i) {
      if (delimiters[i] == "") {
        delimiters[i] = "+";
        break;
      }
      else if (delimiters[i] == "+") {
        delimiters[i] = "-";
        break;
      }
      delimiters[i] = "";
    }
  }
  while (delimiters.Any(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)));
}
```

Then, let's compute corresponding values (with a help of *regular expression* we can extract each number from the formula) and filter out required ones:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?:\-|\+)?[0-9]+");

int sumUpTo = 100;

var result = Formulas()
  .Distinct()             // +123456789 == 123456789
  .Where(formula => reg
    .Matches(formula)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value))
    .Sum() == sumUpTo);
```

Finally, let's print the `result` out:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
123-45-67+89
12-3-4+5-6+7+89
12+3+4+5-6-7+89
123+4-5+67-89
-1+2-3+4+5+6+78+9
1+2+3-4+5+6+78+9
12+3-4+5+67+8+9
1+23-4+56+7+8+9     // <- the sample answer in the question
1+2+34-5+67-8+9
1+23-4+5+6+78-9
123+45-67+8-9
123-4-5-6-7+8-9
```

Comment: I do not like the TrimStart+Distinct approach, as it stores all generated combinations together in memory. Altering the generator to avoid duplicities would be more appropriate imho (delimiters[i] = i==0 ? "-" : "+";).